# How to upload images, and videos to a server (Like vemo) and then display them using springboot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

I'm working on a web project and I am required to write some functionality that will
allow a user to upload images/videos, then display them. The problem is that when I start doing some research for how to accomplish that task, I hear a lot of people saying that I should not
save the images in my database, but rather to an external server then just upload the file path
in the form of a string to the database.

Now this concept is completely new to me so I don't even know where to look or how to start. I am
programming in Java and I am using springboot, and hibernate. Could someone please point me in the
correct direction, as I have been googling for hours and I have found nothing that shows me how to
accomplish this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In any one place you need to store the actual image (in byte format) either in an external server or in DB or in project dir. So it would be better to store the images in an external server or user's PC instead of storing in DB as it takes up a lot of space and loading time when many requests are received.

Comment: The [javax.imageio.ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class reads and writes images to a file structure.  On your Windows desktop, images usually go to `C:\Users\(user)\OneDrive\Pictures`  You define a location on your server for pictures and videos.  The directory string, including the name of the file, is what you store in the database.